# Scaling down div height when browser is scaled down

Tags: html, css, browser, scaling

I set a div to `height: 400px;` and `width 100%;`

I want it to become smaller when the browser is scaled down. `max-height: 400px` would be an answer, but then the div becomes 0px high... if you understand what I mean. The div isn't 400px high anymore with max-height: 400px;

The content of the div is text. this text is still visible but I need the whole div to be 400px heigh (for background-color and for the div's below this div).

What I want: i want a div with a min-height but would scale down when the browser is scaled down...

Comment: share http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: probably you should use `min-width`

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense at all. How can you have a div with fixed height that changes height?!

Comment: Sorry if my question doesn't make sense... I'm Dutch, my English isn't that good. I don't want a fixed height literally. I want a height with  a height of 400px but would scale down when browser is scalled.

Comment: Maybe this will help: i want a div with a min-height but would scale down when the browser is scaled down...

Answer (score 1):

> Example codepen: http://cdpn.io/cjyaq

---

Set `height:100%` and `max-height: 400px` to the `div` element

Set also `height: 100%` for both `html` and `body` element

**Relevant CSS**

```
html, body { padding: 0; margin: 0; height: 100%; }

div { 

  border: 3px red solid;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  height: 100%; max-height: 400px; 
}
```

---

Note: [if your browser is modern enough](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units) and it supports `vh/vw` units is not necessary to set the height of body and html elements: just apply

```
height: 100vh; max-height: 400px;
```

on your div element

Comment: HU!?? Never heard of 100vh! Does internet explorer supports 100vh? because it is working quite good actually..

Comment: It should work fine from `IE9` (included) - see the link I've provided

Answer (score 0):

Assign both height:100% and max-height:400px to the DIV.

Comment: As height:100% inherits parent's height, make sure parent has height in the first place - use chromes web inspector or similar tool to make sure. If your DIV is inside BODY tag, I recommend setting BODY's height 100% as well. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7c3fb/